# Is this an uncommon PNG ending or image steganography?

Tags: steganography, image

I'm reading about image steganography at the moment. I got a test file to experiment with. I noticed a strange code block at the end of the PNG file when I opened it with vim:

```
xref
0 14
0000000000 65535 f
0000007361 00000 n
0000000019 00000 n
0000000209 00000 n
0000007504 00000 n
0000000229 00000 n
0000006570 00000 n
0000006591 00000 n
0000006783 00000 n
0000007097 00000 n
0000007274 00000 n
0000007306 00000 n
0000007603 00000 n
0000007700 00000 n
trailer
<</Size 14/Root 12 0 R
/Info 13 0 R
/ID [ <9AED3720B5C23ED368E99654D498CF4A>
<9AED3720B5C23ED368E99654D498CF4A> ]
/DocChecksum /B1C5AEC599F1457AC4BB4C058905BFD9
>>
startxref
7875
%%EOF
```

Is this a usual ending for PNG files or did I discover hidden (but not understandable) information?

Comment: That is not a PNG file.

Comment: These are the last lines from the file I obtained when I open it in vim. And the file is displayable and shows a logo. So it is somehow valid PNG.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**That block seems to contain PDF syntax.**

[Here](http://lotabout.me/orgwiki/pdf.html) you can find information about the PDF format. The page provides this sample file where you might recognize the syntax for the cross-reference table (`xref`) and the `trailer` section:

```
%PDF-1.7
1 0 obj
  << /Type /Catalog
     /Pages 2 0 R
  >>
endobj

2 0 obj
  << /Type /Pages
     /Kids [3 0 R]
     /Count 1
  >>
endobj

3 0 obj
  << /Type /Page
     /Parent 2 0 R
     /MediaBox [0 0 600 400]
     /Resources << >>
  >>
endobj

xref
0 4
00000000000 65535 f
00000000010 00000 n
00000000069 00000 n
00000000141 00000 n
trailer
  << /Root 1 0 R
     /Size 4
  >>
startxref
249
%%EOF
```